# extracting mass and stiffness matrices from ANSYS

Tags: ansys

I am trying to extract both mass and stiffness sparse matrices from modal analysis using ANSYS 15 software, i used next code :

```
  !Stiffness
  *SMAT, MatKS, D, import, full, file.full, stiff
  *SMAT, Nod2Bcs, D, import, full, file.full,NOD2BCS
  *print, MatK, matKS.txt 
  *export, MatKS, mmf, matKSMMF.txt 
  !Mass
  *SMAT, MatMS, D, import, full, file.full, MASS
  *SMAT, Nod2Bcs, D, import, full, file.full,NOD2BCS
  *print, MatMS, matMS.txt 
  *export, MatMS, mmf, matMSMMF.txt
```

I received 2 files in MMF format, one for the mass(matMsmmf.txt) and the other for stiffness (matKSMMF.txt). When I try to apply upper commands for ANSYS 19 or ANSYS 21 i receive next error arise:

```
*SMA command fails to open the file  file.full
```

I need some code to overcome this problem or the name of the file that contains required data rather than file.full

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I used the next APDL code with ANSYS Workbench 22R1 and it worked :

```
/AUX2 
COMBINE,FULL ! Combine .FULL files
/POST1
*SMAT,MatKS,D,IMPORT,FULL,file.full,STIFF
*SMAT,MatMS,D,IMPORT,FULL,file.full,MASS
*export,MatKS,mmf,matK_MMF.txt
*export,MatMS,mmf,matM_MMF.txt
```

It worked pretty well and gave me neat files in mmf format

Answer (score 1):

I tried running your snippet on ANSYS 2021 R1 and the matrices were not written, but I did not get the stated error.
My guess is there was something changed in the order in which *SMAT and *export have to be executed.
I can think of two solutions:

**1. APDL**

I export the matrices like this:

```
! Gets Stiffness Matrix
*SMAT, MatK, D, import, full, file.full, stiff
*export, MatK, mmf, matkMMF.txt ! Exports Stiffness as MMF format   

! Gets Mass Matrix
*SMAT, MatM, D, import, full, file.full, mass
*export, MatM, mmf, matMMMF.txt ! Exports mass as MMF format
```

Though I did have to solve the model again for the matrices to be written. If you don't want that look into WRFULL.

**2. Pyansys**

You can also look into Pyansys which offers a great way to control ansys with python. There is an example for exporting stiffness and mass matrices here:
https://mapdldocs.pyansys.com/examples/01-apdlmath-examples/mapdl_vs_scipy.html#sphx-glr-examples-01-apdlmath-examples-mapdl-vs-scipy-py

```
from ansys.mapdl.core import launch_mapdl
mapdl = launch_mapdl()
mm = mapdl.math
mapdl.finish()
mm.free()
k = mm.stiff(fname="file.full")
M = mm.mass(fname="file.full")
```

From here you can interact with the matrices.

Comment: unfortunately the APDL method didn't work (fails to open file.full)

Comment: Is the file.full being created in the solver files directory? In Workbench you can look it up by Right-Clicking on the "Solution"-object in the tree and then Click "Open Solver Files Diretory".

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple there will be a file with jobname.full if it is missing you are likely to get that error. please find that file in working directory and run the commands.